# set "change input source" shortcut from terminal

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal, system-preferences

I would like to have the `defaults` terminal command to set the keyboard shortcuts for selecting the next or previous input sources for the keyboard. They can be changed graphically via system preferences -> keyboard -> shortcuts -> input sources, as shown below:

[image: System Preferences dialog for changing keyboard source input shortcuts]

I began following the instructions from [this blog post](https://pawelgrzybek.com/change-macos-user-preferences-via-command-line/), and found that the settings I want are stored in a deeply nested structure in the defaults:

```
"com.apple.symbolichotkeys" = {
    AppleSymbolicHotKeys = {
        60 = {
            enabled = 1;
            value = {
                parameters = (
                    65535,
                    103,
                    8650752
                );
```

I think I have to set the "enabled" and "parameters" values. I was hoping that `defaults` would simply take a space-separated path to the value to set, but the following does not work:

```
defaults write com.apple.symbolichotkeys AppleSymbolicHotKeys 60 value parameters -array 65535 111 8650752
```

The error message is:

```
defaults[15325:960790] Unexpected argument value; leaving defaults unchanged.
```

How do I correctly set these values from the terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
defaults write "com.apple.symbolichotkeys" "AppleSymbolicHotKeys" -dict-add 36 "{ enabled = 1; value = { parameters = (65535, 103, 8650752); type = 'standard'; }; }"
```

:)

Comment: Although this may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain why and/or how it addresses the issue. Providing this additional context would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please edit your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.  Thanks.

Comment: Well, the original poster simply uses the wrong syntax of the command. He is almost there, and as the man page does not give more information, it is more or less trial and error from here. I had the same problem and trial-errored a lot until I found the solution. There is no man page at apple (or anywhere else I could find) to link to. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Where did you get your `36` value? I had a `60`. The other values are different, too.

Comment: I set the setting as in your screenshot and recorded what had changed, then translated it into "defaults" weird syntax.
Here is some more information about the syntax: http://krypted.com/mac-os-x/defaults-symbolichotkeys/
Maybe that helps a little. :)

Comment: Not working anymore as of Monterey.